# ffmpeg invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg

Have such script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 -- extension, like *.MP4
# $2 -- output file name

ffmpeg -f concat -i <(find . -name '$1' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n" | sort) -c copy $2
```

Trying to concatenate MP4 file, get error:

> /dev/fd/63: Invalid data found when processing input

What the problem could be? Using Linux Mint 18, based on Ubuntu 16.04.

P.S. I see the problem is $1 is not substituted in quote - '$1'. Hard coded for now. How to substitute?

Comment: `%1` `%2` look like Windows CMD parameters.  In bash parameters are `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: What is the list of MP4 files you are getting?  Are you sure all of them are actual MP$ files?

Comment: @StephenHarris, changed to $1 - same error.

Comment: @grochmal, yes, files are mp4, play correctly in smplayer.

Comment: see the problem is $1 is not substituted in quote - '$1'. Hard coded for now. How to substitute?

Comment: Use `"$1"` and _not_ `'$1'`

Comment: @StephenHarris, `find` requires quote. Any way out?

Comment: Inside single quotes variables references using `$` don't get interpreted.

Comment: And you can escape double quotes inside doubles using `\"` but I have a hard time getting what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @phk, I'd like to concatenate all MP4 files in a folder, however I see I can specify any other extension, so I'd like to customize this for future.

Comment: You can always do `var=\*.MP4` and then `find . -name "$var"`, the double quotes will prevent globing.  See what `echo "* - *" does`

Answer (score 1):

This works - moved extension outside quotes as `-name` flag allows it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 -- extension, like MP4
# $2 -- output file name

echo Extension: $1
echo Output: $2

echo Files:
find . -name \*.$1 -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n" | sort

ffmpeg -f concat -i <(find . -name \*.$1 -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n" | sort) -c copy $2
```

Comment: I'd suggest  `… -name "*.$1" …` in case the extension contains a space, not that it should. Also, find *does not care* and actually *does not even know* about the quoting (but your shell does!).